# Add value to generic dictionary by key

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic dictionary I instantiate with a key, but a null value, because I need to build the value, out of an iteration, that can only be added to a unique key afterwards.

My question, is there an elegant way to add the instantiated collection to the dictionary by it's key?

My situation:

Values get stored in a collection of records' description block

```
[1]|[Category reference]
[2]|[Category reference]
[3]|[Category reference]
[1]|[Category reference 1]
[2]|[Category reference 2]
```

From this, I do a split on the the pipe {|} item, and then pull the category value and add that to an entity object, for each iteration out of this:

```
// I have a dictionary object to be used for categorization
Dictionary<string, List<FieldItem>> dict = 
                                    new Dictionary<string, List<FieldItem>>();

// need to store each field item in a List<T>
List<FieldItem> items = new List<FieldItem>();

// then I iterate each record from my data source, 
// and get the category from description
foreach (var item in records)
{
    string category = item.Description
                          .Split(new char[] { '|' })[1]
                          .Trim(new char[] { '[', ']');

    // this will give me the category for each item
    FieldItem fi = new FieldItem { Category = category }; // more items will be added

    if (!dict.Keys.Contains(category))
       dict.Add(category, null);

    items.Add(fi);   
}

// now, I have the List<FieldItem> collection and 
// each one contains a category, I now need to add this List<FieldItem>
// collection to Dictionary<string, List<FieldItem>> based on the
// category, so I tried this:

foreach (var kvp in dict.Keys)
{
    var addItem = items.Where(x => x.Category.Equals(kvp)).ToList(); // gives me collection

    // would it be elegant to delete the key from the collection first?
    // cannot do a delete here as the Dictionary is in use, so
    // thought of adding my items to a new Dictionary??

    dict.Add(kvp, addItem);
}
```

Comment: `Apologies if this question had been asked before, **I did not look..**` Made me down vote and continue with the rest of my daily business.

Comment: You must be fun at parties, @MikedeKlerk.  Upvoted as it is a decent question.

Comment: @Moo-Juice It doesn't have to anyting with me being fun at parties, but the downvote button states clearly `This question does not show any research effort`. `I did not look..` convinced me that this was actually the case.

Comment: Why can't you  add a new Category with an empty List of FieldItems and just add  FieldItems to the dict directly in the first foreach

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 like? sorry, your question is a bit confusing. instead of a null value, add an empty List<T> and then add each iteration to the empty List<T>?

Comment: `Apologies if this question had been asked before, I did not look...` loosely translated to: "I'm too lazy, could you fix this for me?" And that without even saying "Thank you" somewhere in your question?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk research is a very generic term, just because I said I did not look on Stackoverflow if the question had been asked before, does not mean I did not research other areas before coming here...

Comment: `I did not look on Stackoverflow if the question had been asked before` Well if you didn't, I would advise you to say you did but couldn't find a similar question. Its a bad habit to come to a resource website and ignore its resources and boldly asking for directions. Whats the purpose of the history of questions if everybody would just ask their question, instead of searching for similar ones first... ? To me that is intolerable behaviour if the quality of this resource site is of any essence.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk it is also a bad practice to flame someone for not being as "well practised" in the art of asking for assistance on a resource web site as yourself. if you have nothing good to say about something you disagree with, rather not say anything at all.

Comment: Stating that I am 'lazy', even though I submitted my attempted efforts as well? I don't have to 'skim' a knowledge base for a possible question similar to mine, if I already showed effort in an attempt to solve this problem myself. My question was if there is a more elegant solution, not for a solution to be handed to me on a silver platter.

Comment: @JadedEric Let me put it this way. Without searching you just risk to burden this site with your personal benefit only, because the answer may already be there, and you question could therefore possible not add any value at all. Now your personal benefit, only benefits you, that is, your ego. Now your ego is not only a burden to you in every day life, you also make your ego a burden for this site by acting so selfish and not obeying the 'rules' of any resource site. ` I don't have to  ... if I already showed effort ...` is an assumption. First search, then ask, it's as simply as that.Just try.

Comment: You have issues my friend, on that I would like to apologise for adding a line of copy to a question you took such great offence to. I am also apologising that me asking a question, and the answer therefore benefiting my ego... Die is regtig nie die moeite werd nie!

Comment: For someone who didn't even spend time to answer this question, Mike, you did waste a lot of time anyway :-).  Keep that sh*t real, brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in records)
{
    string category = item.Description
                          .Split(new char[] { '|' })[1]
                          .Trim(new char[] { '[', ']');

    // this will give me the category for each item
    FieldItem fi = new FieldItem { Category = category }; // more items will be added

    if (!dict.Keys.Contains(category))
       dict.Add(category, new List<FieldItem>());

    dict[category].Add(fi);   
}
```

Comment: I should have done it like this instead of make a unclear comment, sorry Eric